# Annotations documentation

Tags: android, android-annotations

I would like to know what happens really happens if my XML file does not contain certain view and I use `@ViewById` annotation to inject that non existing view into an attribute. [Here](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views) is the documentation for this annotation but this case is not considered there. Do you know about any other official documentation describing this?

Comment: **WILD GUESS**: `NPE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injected field simply will be `null`. The `@ViewById` annotation calls `findViewById()` under the hood, which returns `null` if the view with the given ID is not present.